# How to use hotkey on Guest only?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, lubuntu

I'm using Virtualbox Lubuntu guest on Ubuntu host.
When I try to use for example CTRL+ALT+F1 on guest, I get to login menu on host, but guest is not affected at all.
So how to use this hotkey on guest only?

Answer (score 0):

The Guest is its own machine. Set up the Hot Key in the Guest as well. The two settings (Host, Guest) are independent and can be used: both, one, or the other. In this case, you just want Guest, so do not set it up on the Host